# Fixing "No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed" warning

Tags: mysql, django, function, warnings

The below function works fine except it throws a warning 'No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed (errno. 1329)'. and since i start using this function with django there cant be any warning or error because it stop the whole process

any idea how to fix this?

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS objtree_node_add $$
CREATE FUNCTION objtree_node_add(i_name VARCHAR(255), i_parent_id BIGINT, i_type_id    BIGINT) RETURNS bigint(20)
BEGIN

DECLARE a_name VARCHAR(255);

IF NOT i_name RLIKE '^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+$' THEN
    RETURN -1;
END IF;

SELECT name INTO a_name FROM objtree_nodes WHERE parent_id = i_parent_id AND name = i_name;

IF NOT a_name IS NULL THEN
    RETURN -5;
END IF;

...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know where you read that there is no warnings filtering in Django. Django is just Python, so you can use the Python `warnings` module.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", "No data .*")
```

Comment: sr, i know about this because i work in python, but my coleague start working on django recently and told me it isnt possible :) ... so i was looking for another solutions
thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", "No data .*")
```